# MVP Architecture mixed with Rx Observables in Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, mvp, rx-android

Where would an Observable go in the MVP/MVVM patterns?

In the Model i'm assuming?

I have a background service that is accepting incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

From the examples I have seen, they go in the Model. View layer just setting views, presentation layer mainly pure java. Check out this android project by ribot as an example.

https://github.com/ribot/ribot-app-android

Their observables are in their data manager class which is a part of the model layer. The only difference I might explore, is having multiple data managers.